# Subsetting values even further in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having trouble trying to list all the songs in the 5 genres for this question. I have narrowed down the top 5 genres now I am having issues trying to find all the songs in them.

```
spotify%>%
  group_by(ï..genre)%>%
  summarise(Mean0 = mean(popularity))%>%
  arrange(Mean0,desc())%>%
  top_n(5)%>%
  select(ï..genre)
```

Not sure if there is an easier way to come at this question.

The question asks to create a subset of Spotify data by selecting all the tracks with the top five most popular genres.Call the subset as `spotify_s` and print the tibble `spotify_s`.

The variables include

```
ï..genre,
artist_name,
track_name,
track_id,
popularity,
acousticness,
danceability,
duration_ms,
energy,
instrumentalness,
key,
liveness,
loudness,
mode,
speechiness,
tempo,
time_signature,
valence
```

I can provide more information if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

spotify_s <- spotify %>%
               group_by(ï..genre) %>%
               summarise(Mean0 = mean(popularity)) %>%
               top_n(5, Mean0) %>%
               select(ï..genre) %>%
               left_join(spotify, by = 'ï..genre')
```

Select top 5 genre based on their average popularity, using `left_join` we then keep all the rows for those 5  genre.